# Subspace of newforms one-dimensional with CM $\implies$ unique newform a Poincare series.

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms, automorphic-forms

Let $k \geq 2$. Say $S_{k}^{\text{new}}(\Gamma_{0}(N), \chi)$ is one-dimensional and spanned by a newform with CM, and $S_{k}^{\text{old}}(\Gamma_{0}(N), \chi)$ has positive dimension. Must it be true that $S_{k}^{\text{new}}(\Gamma_{0}(N), \chi)$ is spanned by a Poincare series?

Obviously this is true if $S_{k}(\Gamma_{0}(N), \chi)$ is itself one-dimensional. The Poincare series span the whole cuspidal space, and so there is a basis of Poincare series.

---

**Edit:** This isn't necessarily true when the unique $g \in S_{k}^{\text{new}}(\Gamma_{0}(N), \chi)$ doesn't have CM. I have added this detail.

Comment: Let $p$ be prime inert in CM field of $g$. If $g = \sum_{m} \alpha_{m}P_{m}$, where $\{P_{m}\}$ is basis of Poincare series for $S_{k}(\Gamma_{0}(N),\chi)$, then $0 = a_{g}(p)g = g \mid T(p) = \sum_{m} \alpha_{m}P_{m} \mid T(p) = \sum_{m} \beta_{m}P_{m}$. Then...??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of $$P_{\Gamma_0(N),\chi,k,n}(z)=\sum_{\gamma \in  \langle T\rangle \backslash \Gamma_0(N)} \chi(\gamma)\gamma'(z)^{k/2} \exp(2i\pi n \gamma(z))$$ is that if $f\in M_k(\Gamma_0(N),\chi)$ then the Petersson inner product gives

$$\langle f,P_{\Gamma_0(N),\chi,k,n} \rangle = a_n(f)C_{N,k}$$
So $P_{\Gamma_0(N),\chi,k,1}$ is never orthogonal to $S_k(\Gamma_0(N),\chi)^{old}$ (not a newform), and the span of the $P_{\Gamma_0(N),\chi,k,n},n\ge 1$ represents all the linear maps $S_k(\Gamma_0(N),\chi)\to \Bbb{C}$ so $span(P_{\Gamma_0(N),\chi,k,n},n\ge 1)$ is the whole of $S_k(\Gamma_0(N),\chi)$.

Comment: See my edits. I wanted a CM newform in $S_{k}^{\text{new}}$. The comment below the post may be helpful...

Comment: Sorry I don't get your CM point. Did you mean considering all the $P_{\Gamma_0(N),\chi,n}(z)=\sum_{\gamma \in  \langle T\rangle \backslash \Gamma_0(N)} \chi(\gamma)\gamma'(z)^{k/2} \exp(2i\pi n\gamma(z))$ ? If so the Petersson inner product gives $a_n(f)$ and so you want that $f\mapsto a_n(f)$ is identically zero on the old subspace.

Comment: Don't the $P_{\Gamma_0(N),\chi,n}(z)$ always span the whole cuspidal subspace? Their span (when put as the right term of the Petersson inner product) contains all the linear maps $f\mapsto a_n(f)$ whence all the linear maps $S_k \to \Bbb{C}$ so they are the whole cuspidal subspace.

Comment: The only way the answer to my question is affirmative is if the unique $g \in S_{k}^{\text{new}}$ is the only basis element of $S_{k}$ of order 1 vanishing at $\infty$. If so, then $\langle P_{N, 1}, h \rangle = a_{1}(h) = 0$ for all other basis elements $h \in S_{k}^{\text{old}}$. However, I don't know if such a basis is guaranteed to exist.

Comment: Why is it that $P_{N, \chi, 1}$ is never orthogonal to the old space? I don't see why $a_{1}(h)$ must be non-zero for an $h \in S_{k}^{\text{\old}}$.

Comment: The old subspace contains a Poincare series? (isn't $\chi$ primitive $\bmod d$ a strict divisor of $N$?) The $n=1$ Poincare series's $a_1$ coefficient is (up to a constant) its Petersson norm